# Privacy: API MediaDevices.getUserMedia() and Cache-control: private

Tags: javascript, html, cache-control, privacy-policy

For an experimental website/pwa, I'm using the user's camera stream with MediaDevices.getUserMedia() as background with this:

```
<script>
var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { facingMode: "environment" } })
    .then(function (stream) {
      video.srcObject = stream;
    })
    .catch(function (err0r) {
      console.log("Something went wrong!");
    });
}
</script>
```

and

```
<div id="container">
    <video playsInline="true" muted="true" autoplay="true" id="videoElement">
    </video>
</div>
```

On the same page, under 'head', I have the following meta tag:
`<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="private">`

**My question is: can I be 100% sure that the video stream is stored in the local and private cache of the user's browser? Or are files still stored on the server?**

The aim is to make the website/pwa **as confidential as possible** and I don't want to store **any** user data.

Thank you very much for your support.

Jehane